# How to get the marker been clicked after loading with loadGeoJson call?

Tags: google-maps

I have a long list of points in a GeoJson file, and I'm loading it with:

map.data.loadGeoJson() call.

Each point has an icon on google maps.

I have a click listener to trap when a user click one of those points, and then display an info window. I'm not sure how to get the marker that's been clicked inside the listener, in order to tell the infoWindow where to post, do you guys know?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the clicked marker using (where event is the [DataMouseEvent object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.MouseEvent)):

```
event.feature.getGeometry().get()
```

working code snippet:

```js
// global variables
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  // Create a simple map.
  features = [];
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137.883
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowidow.close();
  });
  // process the loaded GeoJSON data.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function(e) {
    if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
      bounds.extend(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
  // Set click event for each feature.
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    infowindow.setContent('<div style="width:50px;">' + event.feature.getProperty('htmlContent') + '</div>');
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -36)
    });
    infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
    infowindow.open(map);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features":

    [

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.563032, 45.495403]
      },
      "properties": {
        "htmlContent": "point 0"
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.549762, 45.559673]
      },
      "properties": {
        "htmlContent": "point 1"
      }
    }
  ]

};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```